# How to compute $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin n}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the sum of 
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin n}{n!}.$$

I think I am supposed to use the Taylor polynomial of $\ e^x$ but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @graydad I see it's been edited.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\sin x =\Im(e^{ix})$, we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin n}{n!} = \Im\left(e^{e^i}\right) = e^{\cos 1}\sin(\sin 1).$$

[$\Im(z)$ (also written "$\operatorname{Im}(z)$") means the imaginary part of $z$.]

Comment: Perhaps it's better to write \text{Im} , as that notation for "Imaginary" sucks...and many just don't understand it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for your answer. Could you show me the second equality using baby steps please?

Comment: @user1118686 You need to know this formula first: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Do you?

Comment: @user1118686: we have that $\Im$ is a linear operator and for any $z$, $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!}=e^{z},$$ so we plug in $z=e^{i}$ and take the imaginary part.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\sin n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\Im(e^{ix})}{n!}= \Im\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{e^{ix}}{n!}=\Im\left(e^{e^i}\right)=e^{\cos 1}\sin(\sin 1)$

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thanks :). Excuse me for my stupidity

Comment: You know what, you don't even need to know that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Technically, all you need to know is that $(\cos1+i\sin1)^n=\cos(n)+i\sin(n)$ for all integers $n$. That's De Moivre's rule, and it can be proven by induction.

Comment: (Although, writing $e^i$ instead $\cos1+i\sin1$ does save space. It looks like you already know that $e^i=\cos1+i\sin1$, so there's no need to rewrite the post.)